# Implement Push Notifications in your PhoneGap Application

Tags: cordova, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I followed this link to implement push notifications in your phoneGap application. But I'm not getting this output: check the attachment I have uploaded:
I'm stuck with GCM steps please help

Comment: Which link can you please share ? Provide some more information on that what are you doing where you got stuck.

Comment: Where are the links @Sethu?

Comment: http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

Comment: im stuck with Registering  the application with the Google Cloud Messaging service and running  your application . i dont get an output as mentioned under these two  section in the link i provided above